# Select2 with a checkbox list for a multiple select but not getting value

Tags: php, jquery

using this code it's worked. but not getting selected value in $('form').serialize();

```
$('.select2-multiple').select2MultiCheckboxes({
    placeholder: "Choose multiple elements",
})  


<div class="row">
<form id="search_vendor_form">
  <select name="sel-01[]" id="sel-01" class="select2-multiple">
    <option></option>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="CA">California</option>
    <option value="NY">New York</option>
    <option value="TX">Texas</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
  </select>
</div>
</form>
 <div class="row">
</div>
<div class="row">
</div>




jQuery(function($)
{
    $('.select2-multiple').select2MultiCheckboxes({
        placeholder: "Choose multiple elements",
    })`your text`
});
$(document).on('change','#sel-01',function(){
    console.log($(#search_vendor_form).serialize())
})
```

I want to send form value in ajax but not getting in  console.log($(#search_vendor_form).serialize())

Comment: i am using this http://jsfiddle.net/wasikuss/gx93rwnk/

Comment: Have you tried `$('#search_vendor_form').serialize()` instead of `$(#search_vendor_form).serialize()`?

Answer (score 0):

- You have not put your selector in quotes. It has to be a string.
- You seem to have `"your text"` just as a string after a function for some reason, this is not valid and is probably a mistake.
- You need to put all of your JS code *inside* of the wrapping `jQuery(function($){  ...  )}` function.
- Your opening `<div class="row">` element is not closed properly, you seem to have closed it before the `<form>` element, so these two ending tags need to be switched.

below should fix this for you:

HTML

```html
<div class="row">
  <form id="search_vendor_form">
    <select name="sel-01[]" id="sel-01" class="select2-multiple">
      <option></option>
      <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
      <option value="CA">California</option>
      <option value="NY">New York</option>
      <option value="TX">Texas</option>
      <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="row">
</div>
<div class="row">
</div>
```

JS

```js
jQuery(function($){
  $('.select2-multiple').select2MultiCheckboxes({
      placeholder: "Choose multiple elements",
  });

  $(document).on('change','#sel-01',function(){
      console.log($('#search_vendor_form').serialize())
  });
});
```